# Mouse stuttering in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, mouse

I've been using Ubuntu for a while now, and for some reason everytime I drag an object around or move my mouse, it stutters and for a milisecond doesn't respond, so dragging becomes really hard, and gaming.

Comment: @OP which mouse are you using?

Comment: Logitech M510 connected to USB 2.0

Answer (score 2):

I am also using Ubuntu 13.04, with all the current updates, and my Logitech wired mouse started acting up a week or so ago. Today it has been really jerky, and then shuts off entirely. I have to unplug and replug, and then it works for a while until it starts being jerky again.

Here is more information which may lead to an answer:

The syslog has a number of entries about something called "mtp-probe".

```
Sep 29 19:43:57 JW-PC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1"
Sep 29 19:43:57 JW-PC mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.483989] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.731953] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.908125] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c01d
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.908130] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.908134] usb 3-1: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.908137] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.927297] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input86
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC kernel: [103777.927535] hid-generic 0003:046D:C01D.004B: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1/input0

Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1"
Sep 29 20:11:41 JW-PC mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC kernel: [103962.429459] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC kernel: [103962.673386] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC kernel: [103962.793314] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC kernel: [103963.060637] usb 3-1: string descriptor 0 read error: -71
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC kernel: [103963.060645] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c01d
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC kernel: [103963.060648] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC kernel: [103963.064631] usb 3-1: can't set config #1, error -71
Sep 29 20:14:46 JW-PC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1"
```

I've tried other USB ports with similar results. The mouse has been working fine for years until this started recently.

But so far, no solution to the problem. I read a bit about trying to disable mtp-probe, but didn't find a way that worked for me. You might want to check your syslog (under System Tools) to see if there is a series of entries like this.

Answer (score 0):

I installed synaptics (touchpad manager) from the Software Center, then navigate to touchpad configuration, tapping, and disable the four corner options.

I would hope that this wouldn't fix your problem because that would indicate a bug in the synaptic touchpad driver itself, which would be a lot of work for somebody or other.